# Interactivity and touch with Firefox on Microsoft Surface devices?

Tags: javascript, firefox, touch

**On Microsoft touch devices** (such as the Surface Pro), on Chrome and IE it is possible to capture mouse/pointer/touch events, and in the process, prevent scrolling the page.

On Firefox, getting the same level of activity while stopping the page from scrolling with the touch seems impossible. You can stop the page from scrolling by preventing "wheel":

```
can.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  console.log('stopping wheel')
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

But Firefox does not seem to emit mouse/pointer/touch events that you can listen for, so you cannot do the same actions.

There's a live example here:

https://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/PJwMay

**With touch on a Surface:** You can draw on the canvas in Chrome and IE, but you cannot draw on it in Firefox. If you comment out the "wheel" listener, Firefox will additionally scroll the page.

So the question is: **What is needed to get HTML Element touch interactivity in Firefox**, on parity with the other browsers on the system?

Comment: which version of FF?

Comment: Latest or nightly.

Comment: This is just a guess since I can't test this solutions but could adding something like `overflow: hidden;` to the style of the body solve the problem? In which case you can have like a lock icon that toggles it when pressed with a class or something.

Answer (score 8):

Consider using **Touch Events**. And its supported across browsers(Firefox, Chrome, Edge).

Solution is simple, Handle the [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) and prevent defaults.

Consider this example-

```
function startup() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
  log("initialized.");
}

element.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0] // reference first touch point (ie: first finger)
    startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX) // get x position of touch point relative to left edge of browser
    statusdiv.innerHTML = 'Status: touchstart<br> ClientX: ' + startx + 'px'
    e.preventDefault()
}, false)
```

Source : [MDN - Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

Simple demo for Touch Events can be found [here(mdn)](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events$samples/Example?revision=1245069) or [here(jsdfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Darbicus/z3Xdx/10/)

Check this example which would be much more complete([Reference/Demo](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml))-

```
<div class="box" id="box1">
<h3> Touch Me! </h3>
</div>

<h3 id="statusdiv">Status</h3>

<script>

window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1')
    var statusdiv = document.getElementById('statusdiv')
    var startx = 0
    var dist = 0

    box1.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0] // reference first touch point (ie: first finger)
        startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX) // get x position of touch point relative to left edge of browser
        statusdiv.innerHTML = 'Status: touchstart<br> ClientX: ' + startx + 'px'
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)

    box1.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0] // reference first touch point for this event
        var dist = parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - startx
        statusdiv.innerHTML = 'Status: touchmove<br> Horizontal distance traveled: ' + dist + 'px'
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)

    box1.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0] // reference first touch point for this event
        statusdiv.innerHTML = 'Status: touchend<br> Resting x coordinate: ' + touchobj.clientX + 'px'
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)

}, false)

</script>
```

**References:**

- MDN Touch Events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)
- Using Touch Events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events)
- Introduction to Touch events + Scroll + Drag [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml)
- Detecting Swipe using touch [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml)
- Swipe Image gallery [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents3.shtml)
- **Online Paint [demo](https://rbyers.github.io/paint.html) | [code](https://github.com/RByers/rbyers.github.io/blob/master/paint.js)** *This is good!*
- Touch events in detail [here](https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: My code already uses touch events. And mouse and pointer. They do not work here. You'll notice the JSFiddle that you provide, the touches also pan the page.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check online paint and Detecting Swipe using Touch? Those 2 have the complete code and also a good demo of touches and how to handle the cases.
The JSFiddle was only a simple example.